# Generate Anchor Links based on ID (JSON, jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am trying to populate anchor links based on the ID in JSON data.
So far I have this JSON data.

```
{
    "_meta": {
        "status": "ok",
        "api_version": 1,
        "per_page": 20,
        "current_page": 1,
        "total_pages": 5,
        "links": {
            "next": "?page=2",
            "previous": null
        }
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Andrew"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Josh"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "John"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my HTML code.

```
<div id = "links"></div>
```

Here is my jQuery code for fetching ids and displaying them on Anchor.

```
  $.each(json.data, function(entryIndex, entry){
      $("a.names").attr("href", "details?=" + entry.id);
      $("#links").append('<a class = "names">View</a>');
      console.log(entry.id);
    });
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is to generate anchor links in , which would look like this on HTML.

```
<a href = "details?=1">View</a>
<a href = "details?=2">View</a>
<a href = "details?=3">View</a>
```

Instead, the results were,

```
<a href = "details?=3">View</a>
<a href = "details?=3">View</a>
<a href = "details?=3">View</a>
```

So, I debugged using console.log, which returned

```
1
2
3
```

How can I achieve this from getting ID of JSON and assign in Anchor Link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the way you do:

```
$("a.names").attr("href", "details?=" + entry.id);
```

So instead what you need to do is:

```
$("a.names").last().attr("href", "details?=" + entry.id);
```

The above will fetch the last one inserted. **This is a dirty working fix.**

In reality, you must do this way:

```
$.each(json.data, function(entryIndex, entry){
    $("#links").append('<a class="names" href="details?=" + entry.id>View</a>');
    console.log(entry.id);
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
json = {
  "_meta": {
    "status": "ok",
    "api_version": 1,
    "per_page": 20,
    "current_page": 1,
    "total_pages": 5,
    "links": {
      "next": "?page=2",
      "previous": null
    }
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Andrew"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Josh"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "John"
    }
  ]
}
$.each(json.data, function(entryIndex, entry){
  $("#links").append('<a class="names" href="details?=" + entry.id>View</a>');
  console.log(entry.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="links"></div>
```

Comment: This is what exactly I'm searching for. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome. I have also added a snippet. Have a look @user3422381.